# while loops proper nesting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am seeking assistance on properly using the following 3 while loops:

```
while choice is None:  ...
while not isinstance (choice, int):  ...
while int(choice) not in range(0,1):  ...
```

Something like this perhaps:

```
while choice is None and not isinstance (choice, int) and int(choice) not in range(0,1):
    print("Invalid option!")
    choice = input("Choose key: ")
```

How would I properly nest this?

```
choice = None
choice = input("Choose key: ")

while choice is None:
    choice = input("Choose key: ")

while not isinstance (choice, int):
    print("choice is an integer and I equal 0 or 1")
    print("Also if I am None or not an int, I will loop until I meet I am")

while int(choice) not in range(0,1):
    choice = input("Choose key: ")
    choice = int(choice)
```

Comment: I'd prefer using recursion for things like this :)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to happen. What is the purpose the of the while loop(s)? Are you trying to ask the user for input until they give a valid response? Please see [mcve] and describe the desired result.

Comment: Use `while True` and if-statements with `break`? That may be clearer than a series of while loops.

Comment: So is your aim to get a valid integer input?

Comment: Note that `choice` will never be equal to `None`, except on the first line.

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @Jaxi Recursion is the wrong choice for this kind of loop in Python, as it imposes an arbitrary upperbound and a performance penalty compared to a `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get a valid integer which matches an integer from range(0,1). Thanks for the for the links above!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can condense this nicely by moving everything into one loop:

```
while True:
    choice = input("Choose key: ")
    if choice in ("0", "1"):
        choice = int(choice)
        break
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution! I hadn't considered just testing against a `"1", "0"` instead of converting.  Neat.

Answer (score 3):

`input` returns a `str` object, period. It will never return `None`, it will never return an `int`. Just (try to) convert `choice` to an `int`, then check the resulting value, breaking only when a 0 or 1 is entered.

```
while True:
    choice = input("Choose key: ")
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if choice in (0, 1):
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I am new to programming. I was no expecting something so clean and elegant. Thank you chepner!

Comment: I would accept [@chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51787013/1126841) instead, as it delays the call to `int` until you have an input you know won't raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an integer input...

```
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input('Enter choice: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid choice')
    else:
        # add an if statement here to add another condition to test the int against before accepting input
        break
# .... do whatever next with you integer
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corrently this is less about nesting and more about ordering, right? How about:

```
In [10]: choice = None

In [11]: while (
...:     not choice or
...:     not choice.isdigit() or
...:     int(choice) not in range(0,2)
...: ):
...:     print("Invalid option!")
...:     choice = input("Choose key: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
choice = None
while choice not in range(0,1):
    choice = int(input("Choose key: "))
```

I don't know if that's what you were trying to do

Comment: `isinstance()` won't raise an error, it will just return `False`

Comment: Just as a side note, I don't recommend using `isinstance()` for type checking, as it is unpythonic. Following the `Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission (EAFP)` motto, using a `try/except` block to attempt to convert to an integer is preferred. When coding, we assume we **can** do something, and if we can't, handle the exception appropriately.

Comment: I don't know much yet about python and dev in general as I'm a beginner. I didn't know the right ways of using the try/except blocks, and wanted to use what OP used in his code for the `isinstance()`part. I'll keep that in mind next time, thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Have a search for "EAFP" or "duck typing" if you're interested :)